# How to regain warnings about permanent version storage?

Tags: macos, versions

With Preview in Mountain Lion, I carelessly checked the box –

[√] Do not show this message again

– *imagining* that the preference was for just **one** volume.

Then realised that the warning (the sheet):

- no longer appears for Preview, with **other** volumes that do not support permanent version storage
- continues to appear for apps other than Preview, with the volume where I don't require the warning.

In other words, I imagined wrong. The preference may be **app**-specific, not volume-specific.

Please:

- how do I regain the warnings in Preview?

Already I sped through `~/Library/Preferences` sorted by modification date, and opened a few files including `com.apple.finder.plist` but at a glance:

- I can't find any `.plist` with content that includes the string *revision*

If the preference is elsewhere in `com.apple.finder.plist`: where?

(I'd prefer to not abandon that file – it's 35 KB with 3,417 lines.)

Also I viewed the content of recently modified `.plist` files relating to Preview. Unless I'm missing something, nothing relating to revisions, versions or storage. `com.apple.Preview.plist` is **not** recently modified –

[image: com.apple.Preview.* preference files]

– and within those nine, the two that are recently modified seem to contain nothing relating to permanent version storage:

[image: screenshot of a .plist in TextWrangler]

[image: screenshot of a .plist in TextWrangler]

Any other ideas on how to correct my mistake? – Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you rather look at `*preview.plist` instead of `*finder.plist`?

Comment: @patrix already done, please see [revision 2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/70740/2) of the question. In revision 3 there's additional detail.

Comment: Why don't you find out which, if any, .plist is involved just by saving them elsewhere, letting the System to create new ones, and just replace these with the old ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For apps that are not sandboxed

Example:

### To regain warnings about permanent version storage for Apple Pages

Quit the app, then a one-line command in Terminal:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Pages NSDocumentSuppressTempVersionStoreWarning -int 0
```

– in the `Preferences` area that's familiar to users of Snow Leopard and less.

## For apps that are sandboxed

The operating system uses a different approach to containment of some preferences:

`~/Library/Containers/<bundle_id>/Data/Library/Preferences`

Example:

### To regain warnings about permanent version storage for Apple Preview

Quit the app, then a one-line command in Terminal:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview NSDocumentSuppressTempVersionStoreWarning -int 0
```

#### Thoughts

I should have thought first of `~/Library/Containers` when, in the question, I observed –

> `com.apple.Preview.plist` is **not** recently modified

– but I didn't realise what was going on until after I used [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) to visualise writes for a different user of the OS.

[image: screenshot of Quick Look of a sandboxed preference file for Preview]

---

## References

[App Sandbox Design Guide: Migrating an App to a Sandbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html)

[A visual record of me finding the relevant key in the `.plist` for Pages](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2012/11/08/a/?mode=gallery)

[A visual record of me finding the relevant key in the `.plist` for Preview](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2012/11/08/b/?mode=gallery)